# how to sort value before concatenate text columns in pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I need help to convert below code in Pyspark code or Pyspark sql code.

`df["full_name"] = df.apply(lambda x: "_".join(sorted((x["first"], x["last"]))), axis=1)`

Its basically adding one new column name **full_name** which have to concatenate values of the columns first and last in a sorted way.

I have done below code but don't know how to apply to sort in a columns text value.

```
df= df.withColumn('full_name', f.concat(f.col('first'),f.lit('_'), f.col('last')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **Spark-2.4+**:

We can use **`array_join, array_sort`** functions for this case.

**Example:**

```
df.show()
#+-----+----+
#|first|last|
#+-----+----+
#|    a|   b|
#|    e|   c|
#|    d|   a|
#+-----+----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
#first we create array of first,last columns then apply sort and join on array
df.withColumn("full_name",array_join(array_sort(array(col("first"),col("last"))),"_")).show()
#+-----+----+---------+
#|first|last|full_name|
#+-----+----+---------+
#|    a|   b|      a_b|
#|    e|   c|      c_e|
#|    d|   a|      a_d|
#+-----+----+---------+
```